# Javascript, how to check the all the attributes of an object? Is possible compare it with a schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, object, object-comparison

I have an application in Node.js that have a REST service, this service (with POST Method) accept a JSON passed as payload in the body request.

The JSON payload is parsed so I have an Object, at this point I'd like check that all mandatory fields are presents.

I have to check it field by field or there is a way to compare the object to a defined schema?

Which is the best approch?

Comment: You can define a JSON Schema (https://json-schema.org/) and then use a schema validator (for instance https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) to validate the data against the schema

Comment: Note that the JSON schema spec is still a draft

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`Joi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) for schema creation and validating.